# angular4 dynamic image src issue

Tags: html, angular

I have an `img` tag is which `src` populated dynamically.

```
<img [src]="dynamicUrl" loader >
```

`dynamicUrl` is a variable that is populated with an ajax call's result.

```
dynamicUrl:string ="";
```

`loader` is a directive in which I have done

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
  let loadingBackground = `background:url("${this.loadingImg}") 50% no-repeat`;
  this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, "style", loadingBackground);

  this.el.nativeElement.onerror = () => {
     // set the error icon as background
     let errorBackground = `background:url("${this.errorImg}") 50% no-repeat`;
     this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, "style", errorBackground);
  };
}
```

Now when the directive is called and control comes to `ngAfterViewInit` it sets the `loadingImg` gif to the background, and loader shows for milliseconds on the screen. As default value of `dynamicUrl` is an empty string (so `src` resolved to ("http://localhost:3000/")) so it also show missing image icon with loader and it gets in the `onerror` method and sets the `errImg` as background, so the error image is visible on the screen.

Now the `defaultUrl` value get it original value populates so actual image is visible.

How can I show solve this, I just want to show only loader image until the actual image get downloaded in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can put loader directive within div element;

```
<div loader *ngIf="dynamicUrl == null || dynamicUrl == ''"> </div>

<img [src]="dynamicUrl" *ngIf="dynamicUrl !=null && dynamicUrl != ''">
```